# c# exporting data from datagridview into excel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

i have a winforms application and i want to export data from the datagridview into excel. how would i do this? thank u for any help

i want the simplest approach.

maybe exporting to CSV is easier?

Comment: Please see article 

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667291/how-to-export-c-sharp-datagridview-into-excel/22145663#22145663

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a number of options

1. Write the data to a comma separated value (csv) file
2. Use OleDB to write to create an Excel file and write the data to it
3. Use the OOXML SDK to create an Excel file
4. Write the data to an XML file that can be read by Excel
5. Use the NPOI library to create and write to the Excel file

Those are a few options off the top of my head. Personally I would go with NPOI, I have used this in server based solutions and it is really easy to work with and quite fast. However it does not currenly support the xlsx file format, only standard xls. 
The library can be found [here](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)

I also found [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), supports xlsx, but I cannot vouch for it since I have not personally used it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to write the data to an XML file and then import that into Excel.

There's a [`WriteXML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwzeas3z.aspx) method on the `DataTable` class that will write the schema out as well so when you import it into Excel all your column headings will be imported as well.

It has the added advantage that you can import the data into other XML aware packages as well.

Comment: I agree, just iterate the rows in a foreach loop and export your cells to an xml file. This will really make it easy to import the data in a myriad of locations.

Comment: @pstrjds - if you want a simple data dump then you don't even have to iterate over the data yourself. `WriteXML` will do it all for you. Obviously if you want to filter the data then you do need to do more work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways if you search Google. Here is one:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hrojasara/2904/

Comment: The article linked works as long as the user has excel on the machine. If you are looking for something more generic where it is exported into a format that can be imported into excel and does not require Excel to be installed than I would go with the XML output suggested by ChrisF.

Comment: If you include the Excel DLL required and include it with your application when distributing it, Excel does not need to be installed on the user's computer.

Comment: you can distribute the PIA's but I don't think they work without Office installed, and actually reading the EULA in the Office PIA it sure sounds like you aren't allowed to install them if Office isn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use something like the OpenDocument toolkit to create a "Spreadsheet" using the OpenDocument format. This way it can be opened in Excel, OpenOffice, LibreOffice, etc.
http://odftoolkit.org/projects/aodl/downloads
Here is a link to code snippets for the toolkit
http://odftoolkit.org/projects/aodl/pages/AODL-examples
Link to example creating a spreadsheet
http://odftoolkit.org/projects/aodl/pages/AODL-example-1